# Roadmap to geometric Langlands for a mathematical physics student

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, geometric-representation-theory, geometric-langlands, learning-roadmap

I am a student of both mathematics and physics, who has recently been studying string theory. My mathematics background is mostly differential geometry (principal bundles, Lie groups, etc.), although starting this semester I am planning to study algebraic geometry and Lie algebras (particularly infinite dimensional Lie algebras, such as current algebras). Now, in the long term, I am interested in studying the connections between $\mathcal N = (2,0)$ superconformal field theory and geometric Langlands as well as the connections between $S$-duality and the latter, as described in the following papers of Witten: [Geometric Langlands From Six Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2720) and [Electric-Magnetic Duality And The Geometric Langlands Program](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0604151).

Now, let's suppose that someone has understood algebraic geometry at the level of Hartshorne, superstring theory at the level of [Green, Schwarz, & Witten](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107029112), and Lie algebras at the level of the book [Current Algebras and Groups](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1475702973) or Kac's [Infinite Dimensional Lie Algebras](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521466938). What then would be the best roadmap (of books, papers, etc.) to learn about the remaining prerequisites of the geometric Langlands correspondence? I am aware of the book [Representation Theory and Complex Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817649379) by Ginzburg and Chriss for geometric representation theory, but after this, what should one use to study geometric Langlands? What prerequisites remain, and how should one best go about learning them?

Comment: Edward Frenkel has some introductory notes on conformal field theory and the Langlands program which are pretty good. You could start there and learn things as you need them. Since the field is pretty massive where you should go from there depends on your interests

Comment: Are you referring to https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512172 ?

Comment: That’s the one!

Comment: Also, some ideas which feature heavily in modern versions of the theory (and are absent from those notes) are higher category theory and derived algebraic geometry. The former is used everywhere (often in the guise of DG categories), and the latter is mostly used on the “spectral” side of things. For example, the derived geometric Satake equivalence of Bezrukavnikov and Finkelberg is an equivalence of two stable infinity categories, one of which is (Ind)-coherent sheaves on a derived scheme

Comment: Do you have any good references for those topics?

Comment: Lurie’s book “Higher Topos Theory” is a classic reference for infinity categories, and the book “A Study in Derived Algebraic Geometry” by Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum is a pretty good introduction to DAG the way geometric Langlands theorists typically think about it. That said, there are probably numerous shorter/more user-friendly introductions to both subjects online

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Markus Land's book [Introduction to Infinity-Categories](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-61524-6) may be a friendlier introduction to $\infty$-categories than Lurie's book.

Comment: @TimothyChow Thanks, I'll add it to my reading list for $\infty$-categories.

Comment: I would actually actively recommend against reading any source on $\infty$-categories (unless you are intrinsically interested in them). The power of $\infty$-categories is that, once you understand the philosophy, they are very convenient to use, without having to delve into their foundational details. For the purposes of geometric Langlands, you will learn much more from seeing how they are used than actually reading about them...

Comment: By the way, there are many different approaches to GL. If you have a concrete goal in mind (e.g., "I want to understand this paper _______ by ______") I can write a longer form answer giving a roadmap.

Comment: @dhy sure thing. I am interested in understanding the above linked papers by Witten, as well as the following paper of Aganagic, Frenkel, and Okounkov: https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.03146. In general, the connections between string/M-theory (in particular the $\mathcal N = (2,0)$ superconformal field theory) and GL.

Comment: @DanielWaters Is there a specific mathematical point you get stuck at when you try to read Kapustin-Witten? I would say those papers are written to require quite a bit of physics background and not very much math background (e.g. the introduction contains the sentence "No prior familiarity with the Langlands program is assumed; instead, we assume a familiarity with subjects such as supersymmetric gauge theories, electric-magnetic duality, sigma-models, mirror symmetry, branes, and topological field theory.")

Comment: @DanielWaters In particular if Kapustin-Witten is your goal, $\infty$-categories, DAG, "classical" geometric representation theory, etc., are certainly not necessary prerequisite knowledge.

Comment: I have not read the paper as of yet, but I would like to be familiar with things like Hecke eigensheaves and $\mathcal D$-modules before reading the paper, as I like to have a solid background before diving into new things (as the conformal field theory and string theory part, I am still in the process of learning those things, and I don't need any recommendations for them at the moment) . But aside from Kapustin-Witten, I would need to know a bit about geometric representation theory for the paper by Aganagic, et. al.

Comment: @DanielWaters My point is that neither Hecke eigensheaves (which is just a definition) nor D-modules should be considered background for Kapustin-Witten, because they only really use the definitions (which they provide and explain.) There is of course independent value in learning about D-modules and why they appear in GRT (the book of Hotta-Takeuchi-Tanisaki is one place to learn this if you are interested) but I don't think knowing this theory will help for reading Kapustin-Witten.

Comment: AFO on the other hand does require more mathematical background. This is not so close to what I do so take everything I say with a grain of salt, but my impression is that this is closely related to the general story of quantum enumerative geometry of symplectic resolutions, of which the prototypical case is the paper "Quantum Cohomology of the Springer Resolution" by Braverman-Maulik-Okounkov. After that I would suspect the paper to read is "Quantum Groups and Quantum Cohomology" by Maulik-Okounkov?

Comment: Okay great, I will keep all of this saved so that I know what to read when the time comes. I am interested in learning the GRT as well, which is part of why I was saying that about Kapustin-Witten, although I wasn't really aware of the self-contained nature of the paper. Thanks for all of your recommendations and advice!